# ProgressDialog doesn't show up. Again

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm confused because this has been working for me quite fine in other activities, and here I just basically copy-pasted the code, but ProgressDialog doesn't show up. Here's the code:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);          
             final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);        
             progress.setProgressStyle(STYLE_SPINNER);
             progress.setIndeterminate(true);
             progress.setMessage("Working...");
             progress.show();
             Thread thread = new Thread() 
                {          
                  public void run() 
                  {

                      //long operation populating the listactivity
                      progress.dismiss();
                  }
                };
                thread.run();               
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the root cause of your problem, but try executing thread.start() instead of thread.run().  Executing start() will actually start a new thread and maybe give the progress dialog a chance to show.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to manage the long operation.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<HttpResponse, Integer, SomeReturnObject>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    long totalSize;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected SomeReturnObject doInBackground(HttpResponse... arg0)
    {
        // Do long running operation here           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        // If you have a long running process that has a progress 
        pd.setProgress((int) (progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SomeReturnObject o)
    {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above code, it's actually showing the dialog and closing it immediately in the Thread run() method. If you really want to see if it shows put a Thread.sleep(2000) to test, but yes what John Russell said is the way to go to use an AsyncTask instead.